# Compacting if else statement into shorter more elegant code

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following if-else block, and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way this code could be written... I am using Java 8

```
if(valueString != null) {
    return valueString;
}
else if(valueInt != null) {
    return String.valueOf(valueInt);
}
else if(valueFloat != null) {
    return String.valueOf(valueFloat);
}
else if(valueDate != null){
    return String.valueOf(valueDate);
}
else if(valueBit != null) {
    return String.valueOf(valueBit);
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Where do all these `value*` variables come from?

Comment: Use a list<object>

Comment: Are your values mutually exclusive / is that order corresponding to the desired priorities of the return values?

Comment: You don't actually have to use if-else since you are returning values. You could directly use if as the function ends when a return statement is executed

Comment: It smells bad design as hell

Comment: First, if you returning first you don't need any else statement

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a stream and go through all the values and return null if none of them is not null.

```
return Stream.of(valueString, valueInt, valueFloat, valueDate, valueBit)
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .map(String::valueOf)
             .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj instead of `x -> x != null` you can use `Objects::nonNull`. I find a method reference looking nicer than a lambda, but that's really just a preference.